# Angular ui-router stateProvider as chainable object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Angular UI-Router is a routing framework, when I was searching for how to use UI router I found two approaches for using it, the `async` state method invoke, and the `sync` state method invoke as in:

**Sync:**

```
$stateProvider
    .state('state1', {
      url: "/state1",
      templateUrl: "partials/state1.html"
    })
    .state('state1.list', {
      url: "/list",
      templateUrl: "partials/state1.list.html",
      controller: function($scope) {
        $scope.items = ["A", "List", "Of", "Items"];
      }
    })
    .state('state2', {
      url: "/state2",
      templateUrl: "partials/state2.html"
    })
    .state('state2.list', {
      url: "/list",
      templateUrl: "partials/state2.list.html",
      controller: function($scope) {
        $scope.things = ["A", "Set", "Of", "Things"];
      }
    });
});
```

**Async:**

```
$stateProvider
    .state('state1', {
      url: "/state1",
      templateUrl: "partials/state1.html"
    });
$stateProvider
    .state('state2', {
      url: "/state2",
      templateUrl: "partials/state2.html"
    })
```

the question is there any difference between two methods, and is any method better than other, and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say, that there is NO `async` or `sync` *syntax*. It is just a ***`fluent`*** *syntax*.

The method **`$stateProvider.state(...)`**, has this implementation,

#### [state.js](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/blob/master/src/state.js#L681)

```
function state(name, definition) {
    /*jshint validthis: true */
    if (isObject(name)) definition = name;
    else definition.name = name;
    registerState(definition);
    return this;
}
```

where the most important is last line - **`return this;`**. That is just a fluent syntax:

#### [Fluent interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface)

> ...
>   A fluent interface is normally implemented by using method cascading *(concretely method chaining)* to relay the instruction context of a subsequent call *(but a fluent interface entails more than just method chaining)*. Generally, the context is
>
> - defined through the **`return value`** of a called method
> - ...

Other words, these are the same:

```
// not fluent syntax
$stateProvider.state(name1, {..}) // returned value not used
$stateProvider.state(name2, {..}) // returned value not used

// fluent in place
$stateProvider
   .state(name1, {..}) // returned value is $stateProvider again
   .state(name2, {..}) // returned value not used
```